# PySpark Cassandra Connector efficiently querying across partition keys

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm faced with the following problem using PySpark and dataframes with the cassandra-connector. My Cassandra data lake consists of metric measurements across (network) devices, and the entries are of type (device,interface,metric,time,value).

My cassandra table for the raw data has:

```
PRIMARY KEY ((device,interface,metric),time)
```

for supposedly efficient fetching of time ranges for a given measurement.

Now for reporting purposes, users can query any set of device/interface/metric combinations (ie give me a specific metric for all interfaces of a device). Now I know the list of each, so I'm not looking to do wildcard searches, but rather IN queries.

I'm using Spark 1.4, so I'm adding filters like to obtain dataframes to calculate min/max/percentile/etc... on the recorded metric values.

```
metrics_raw_sub = metrics_raw\
                    .filter(metrics_raw.device.inSet (device_list))\
                    .filter(metrics_raw.interface.inSet (interface_list))\
                    .filter(metrics_raw.metric.inSet (metric_list))
```

This isn't very efficient as these predicates do not get pushed down to CQL (only the last predicate can be an IN query), so I'm pulling in tons of data and filtering on the client side. (not good)

Why doesn't cassandra-connector allow multiple IN predicates across partition columns? Doing this in a native CQL shell appears to work?

Another approach to my problem above would be to (and this yields efficient individual queries as predicates are pushed down to Cassandra):

```
for device in device_list:
    for interface in interface_list:
        metrics_raw_sub = metrics_raw\
                .filter(metrics_raw.device == device)\
                .filter(metrics_raw.interface == interface)\
                .filter(metrics_raw.metric.inSet (metric_list))
```

And then run the aggregation logic for each subquery, but I feel like this is largely serialising what should be a parallel computation across all requested device/interface/metric values... Can I batch the Cassandra queries so I can run my analytics on one large distributed dataframe?

Bottom line, I'm looking to do this very efficiently. If the turn-around times are short enough, we'll run these on-demand. If not, we'll need to look into pre-computing them and storing into tables (which sacrifices flexibility for doing custom time-range reporting)

Any insights would be *much* appreciated!!
Nik.